# I can't make Javascript code work in WPCode in any way

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a WordPress website where I'm trying to add this small Javascript code which all it have to do is move an image left and right when the user scrolls the page with the mousewheel:

```
let didScroll = false;
let paralaxTitles = document.querySelectorAll(".challenger");

const scrollInProgress = () =\> {
didScroll = true
}

const raf = () =\> {
if(didScroll) {
paralaxTitles.forEach((element, index) =\> {
element.style.transform = "translateX("+ window.scrollY / 10 + "%)"
})
didScroll = false;
}
requestAnimationFrame(raf);
}

requestAnimationFrame(raf);
window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollInProgress)
```

The script works fine if I add it between a <script> tag directly inside a custom HTML widget (yea I know is bad practice, I just used it for testing) and as soon as I am inside the Elementor editor it works the way it should.

I've seen online that in order to add JS on WordPress I need to use WPCode, and here's the issue: I can't understand why but no matter what I do, no matter if I insert the script in header, footer, or body, no matter if I use Global Script or Code Snippet, the script doesn't work in any way and I can't really figure out what I'm doing wrong...

Here's the whole code that as I previously mentioned works in Elementor editor:

HTML + JS

```
<script>
let didScroll = false;
let paralaxTitles = document.querySelectorAll('.challenger');

const scrollInProgress = () => {
  didScroll = true
}

const raf = () => {
  if(didScroll) {
    paralaxTitles.forEach((element, index) => {
      element.style.transform = "translateX("+ window.scrollY / 10 + "%)"
    })
    didScroll = false;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(raf);
}


requestAnimationFrame(raf);
window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollInProgress)
</script>

<div class="track_big">
    <div class="challenger">
        <img src="../wp-content/uploads/2023/09/chall_divisory.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.track_big {
    position:relative;
    background-image: url("../wp-content/uploads/2023/09/track2.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 9px;
    margin-top: 85px;
}

.challenger {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 3325px;
    z-index: 11;
    right: 150%;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.